# Cookie is not working in CakePHP , CookieComponent is not working

Tags: cakephp, cookies

This is my `AdminsController` class where I have included the Cookie Component, and used the cookie creation code given below in #1. #2 is the code I am using in my view.

Whenever I fire the url, it is showing the error: `"Helper class CookieHelper could not be found."`.

Why is this error is showing, as I have asked to use `CookieComponent` to set and get the value of the cookie. I have followed instructions and code syntax from the **CakePHP** docs that they have provided on their website. I'm really having trouble on setting and getting the cookie. I need help on this. The **CakePHP** version that i'm using is 2.6.

**#1 - Controller:**

```
class AdminsController extends AppController {

/**
 * This controller does not use a model
 *
 * @var array
 */
    //public $uses = array('Admin');


/**
 * Displays a view
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws NotFoundException When the view file could not be found
 *  or MissingViewException in debug mode.
 */
    public $components = array('Cookie');

    public function index() {


            $this->layout=false;
            //echo "=users index====";

            //$this->layout = 'adminlayout';


            if($this->request->is('post'))
            {
                        $username = $this->request->data['Admin']['username'];
                        $password = $this->request->data['Admin']['password'];
                        $remember_me = $this->request->data['Admin']['remember_me'];



                        $sql = $this->Admin->find('count',array(
                                    'conditions' => array('Admin.username'=>$username,'Admin.password'=>md5($password))
                                ));

                        //$this->Session->write('is_admin_login','Y');

                        if($sql>0)
                        {

                            $this->Session->write('is_admin_login','Y');
                            if(!empty($remember_me))
                            {
                                //*** set cookie starts

                                if($this->Cookie->check('username_cookie'))
                                {
                                    $this->Cookie->delete('username_cookie');
                                    $this->Cookie->write('username_cookie', $username, false, '30 Days');
                                }

                                if($this->Cookie->check('password_cookie'))
                                {
                                    $this->Cookie->delete('password_cookie');
                                    $this->Cookie->write('password_cookie', $password, false, '30 Days');
                                }   


                                //*** set cookie ends

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if($this->Cookie->check('username_cookie'))
                                {
                                    $this->Cookie->delete('username_cookie');

                                }

                                if($this->Cookie->check('password_cookie'))
                                {
                                    $this->Cookie->delete('password_cookie');

                                }   

                            }


                            $this->redirect('/admin/home');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password','default',array('class'=>'error_msg'));
                        }

            }


            $this->render('admin_login');
    }
}
```

**#2 - AdminLogin View**

```
<div class="form-box" id="login-box">



            <div class="header">Sign In</div>
            <?php echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'Admins', 'action' => 'index')
)); ?>

                <div class="body bg-gray">
                 <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">



                    <?php echo  $this->Session->flash(); ?>

                 </div>
         </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <?php /*?> <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" value="<?php // echo get_cookie("username_cookie"); ?>"/><?php */?>

                        <?php 


                            $options=array();
                            $options['id']='username';
                            $options['class']='form-control';
                            $options['placeholder']='User ID';  
                            $options['label']=false;

                            if($this->Cookie->check('username_cookie'))
                            {
                                $options['value']=$this->Cookie->read('username_cookie');
                            }

                            echo $this->Form->input('username',$options);

                         ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php /*?><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="<?php // echo get_cookie("password_cookie"); ?>"/><?php */?>

                         <?php 


                            $options=array();
                            $options['id']='password';
                            $options['class']='form-control';
                            $options['placeholder']='Password'; 
                            $options['label']=false;

                            if($this->Cookie->check('password_cookie'))
                            {
                                $options['value']=$this->Cookie->read('password_cookie');
                            }   

                            echo $this->Form->input('password',$options);

                         ?>

                    </div>          
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <?php
                                $options=array();
                                $options['id']='remember_me';
                                //$options['class']='form-control';
                                $options['type']='checkbox';
                                $options['label']=false;    
                                $options['div']=false;

                                $checked="";
                                if($this->Cookie->check('username_cookie') || $this->Cookie->check('password_cookie'))
                                {
                                    $options['checked']="checked";
                                }


                                echo $this->Form->input('remember_me', $options);
                        ?> Remember me
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer">                                                               
                    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-olive btn-block">Sign me in</button>  
                    <p><a href="<?php // echo base_url()."admin/login/forgot"; ?>">Forgot my password</a></p>

                </div>
            <?php

             echo $this->Form->end();

              ?>

            <div class="margin text-center">
             <!--   <span>Sign in using social networks</span>-->
                <br/>


            </div>
```

Comment: Formatting should be improved.

Comment: There is no Cookie helper on cakephp you should retrieve Cookie value using normal set method in your controller's action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a Component in a view, which is why it is telling you there is no helper class called `Cookie`.

Use the Cookie component in your Controller action to set a variable, and then use the variable in your view:

Remove these lines from your view:

```
$this->Cookie->check('username_cookie')
$this->Cookie->check('password_cookie')
```

Use them in your controller action to set view variables ...something similar to:

```
$this->set('username_cookie', $this->Cookie->read('username_cookie'));
$this->set('password_cookie', $this->Cookie->read('password_cookie'));
```

Then you will be able to use the set variables in your view:

```
if(!empty($username_cookie)) {
    //do something
}

//or

if(!empty($password_cookie)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: You were right McWayWeb ,  Cookie component cannot be accessed in view  directly , thats  why that error was thrown . My code is working fine :-), thanks for your suggestion